# I can't use Paypal IPN on my Hosting, how to solve this?

Tags: php, ssl, paypal

I'm testing paypal ipn for a website I am building, but it fails when I try to validate the ipn. In particular this line doesn't work:

```
$fp = fsockopen('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

the check `if (!$fp)` fails (fp is false). I assume it can't connect. Why this?

**Update**

I discovered my hosting solution doesn't support ssl, in fact I get:

> Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to
>   ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443 (Unable to find the socket transport
>   "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)

Is there a way to get over this without going for another hosting solution?

Comment: Is curl available? Try that instead.

Comment: If they don't support ssl in php there might be more hidden behind the curtains that makes them unqualified to run an e-commerce site...

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to use SSL (though Paypal highly recommends it.)

```
$fp = fsockopen('www.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

Comment: I changed it to www.sandbox.paypal.com on port 80, but, it gives me 302 found and the answer header has content length of 0... what could be wrong (my pay button is still on https tough).

Comment: It must use SSL. Port 80 is not available for Sandbox, and is only in Live for the time being.